# validate a string for text ,operators and ( [ ]) brackets

Tags: java, regex

i want a regular expression to validate string to have only text,operators and these brackets `([ ])`

Comment: ([price] + [test])  pattern should be like this,operators are +,-,/,*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match these characters:

```
if (str.matches("[a-zA-Z\\[\\]+\\-/*()]*")) {
  ...
}
```

A better version is:

```
if (str.matches("\\s*\\[[a-zA-Z]+\\](\\s*[/*+-]\\s*\\[[a-zA-Z]+\\])*")) {
  ...
}
```

Supporting parentheses is difficult because if you can put expressions in parentheses it is no longer a *regular language* (it is a *context-free language*). Regexes are a poor fit for matching that kind of expression. For that you'll need a PDA (pushdown automaton).

Comment: i jst want + ,- *,/ as operators and ([ ]) and text

Comment: it shld match ([price] + [test])

Answer (score 0):

```
String foo = "[price] + [test]";
System.out.println(foo.matches("\\[[a-zA-Z]+\\] ?[+/*-] ?\\[[a-zA-Z]+\\]"));
```

and if you want to include the parentheses in the String:

```
String foo = "([price] + [test])";
System.out.println(foo.matches("\\(\\[[a-zA-Z]+\\] ?[+/*-] ?\\[[a-zA-Z]+\\]\\)"));
```